# Finding the date 18 years ago

Tags: javascript, datetime

Here's what I have:

```
require('../../src/utils/date-object-to-yyyymmdd');
var eighteenYearsAgo = new Date();
eighteenYearsAgo.setTime(eighteenYearsAgo.valueOf() - 18 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
eighteenYearsAgo = eighteenYearsAgo.yyyymmdd();
```

Basically, I am generate a date, setting it to 18 years ago (from today), and then converting it to yyyy-mm-dd format via an external function. I feel like this is quite verbose as is, but can't quite wrap my head around how to do it in a shorter way.

Comment: You do realize that you haven't taken leap years into consideration, right?

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you use the setFullYear() method?

```
eighteenYearsAgo = eighteenYearsAgo.setFullYear(eighteenYearsAgo.getFullYear()-18);
```

Instead of using the yyymmdd() function, you can also use the Date.toISOString() method. This will also show the time... but you can get rid of it in several ways (split on "T" or use a regular expression).

Comment: Okay sure, good point, but doesn't make the code much terser.

Comment: That's true. But it takes leap years in consideration.

Comment: Ah, very good point. And by the way, my yyyymmdd function is essentially doing what you're saying, toISOString and splitting. Cheers.